# Are "dummy URLs" required to make function calls to Flask from the front-end?

Tags: python, flask

I am making my first web app with Flask wherein a database of drinks is displayed on the front-end based on selected ingredients. Then the user selects a drink and an in-page pop-up appears with some drink info and a button "make", when the user hits "make" it calls some python code on the back end (Flask) to control GPIO on my raspberry pi to control some pumps.

Does this "make" need to call some route (e.g. `/make/<drink>`) in order to call the python function on the back end? I don't like the idea that any user could just enter the URL (`example.com/make/<drink>`) where  is something in the database to force the machine to make the drink even if the proper ingredients are not loaded. Even if I did checking on the back end to ensure the user had selected ingredients were loaded, I want the user to have to user the interface instead of just entering URLs.

Is there a way so that the make button calls the python code without using a "dummy URL" for routing the button to the server?

Comment: If I understand correctly, then yes, you need a route in Flask for the server to accept a client-side action. I don't quite understand what you mean by "dummy URL", but not all functions need a route, if that is what you are saying

Comment: im not asking if all functions need a route, just the ones that are called by buttons on the front end. By "dummy URL" i mean that `/make/<drink>` isnt a URL which displays content. All it is used for is to call the drink making code and then probably redirect the user. I don't want the user to have the ability to just enter the URL to make the drink, i want them to go through the web app.

Comment: Gotcha. So, you are asking a security question. The only thing that comes to mind is hiding a field in the POST data for a [CSRF token](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/3/)

Comment: huh, interesting. so there isn't any way to just call the python code from the front end without requiring a routing URL?

Comment: There shouldn't be. The front-end is all HTML/CSS/JS, no python is loaded/available there.

Comment: i understand that a message must be sent somehow between the two, i was just wondering if there was a way to avoid entering the URL to bypass the interface

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, you can secure the endpoint so that a user has to provide credentials to issue a successful request to that endpoint.

In addition, your endpoint should be using proper HTTP semantics if its creating / updating data.  i.e. `POST` to create a drink, `PUT` to update a drink.  This will also protect you from someone just putting the URL into a browser since that is a `GET` request.

TL;DR

1. Secure the endpoint (if possible)
2. Add checks that the proper request body is provided
3. Use proper HTTP semantics

Comment: I wasn't intending to have a login system, but your other advice seems solid. I guess it would be a POST request? It's not necessarily creating a drink so much as asking the back-end to start code which controls the raspberry pi.

Comment: Yeah, IMO, that would be a POST.  Anytime a request alters server state everytime its performed, it would be considered a POST.

Comment: is it altering the server state? i'm still a beginner so i don't know what is considered "altering" the state.

Comment: That's probably a better question for you.  What exactly happens when the request is  made?  May want to include that in your original question

Comment: i havent started making the app yet, i'm just planning it out. I want to just have a button that corresponds to an item in the database, when it's pressed the front-end tells the back-end to send that database item to some python code which controls my raspberry pi GPIO